# Cannot compile libvorbis (Ogg missing)

Tags: ffmpeg, ogg, oggvorbis

I am following [this guide](http://wiki.webmproject.org/ffmpeg/building-with-libvpx) to compile FFMPEG with libvpx support. On the libvorbis compilation step, I get this error:

```
The test program failed to compile or link. See the file config.log for the exact error that occurred. This usually means Ogg was incorrectly installed or that you have moved Ogg since it was installed.
```

There is no error on the Ogg compilation and installation step, and I cannot find this config.log file. I have libogg available in local/lib and local/bin.

Answer (score 1):

Resolved with the following:

- Correct the path to MinGW in the fstab file in /etc
- add--prefix="path to MinGW" to the configure flags